# Modelling problem

Tags: optimization, algorithms

i have this problem and i have to model it in a boolean formula.
Assuming that variables can have value 0 or 1 and V is OR and ∧ is AND.

I have n boolean variables x1,x2......xn. i want a formula that is always true when the number of one is major than the number of zero.

i have this formula

[image]

And if i think that K=n/2 this work for my problem,but is asymptotically in O($n^{n/2}$).I want that is in O($n^{log n}$) can someone help me?

Comment: It seems to me like it's not really a model theory or boolean algebra problem: what you want is the smallest formulas to check whether there are more ones than twos. It's more algorithmic than model-theoretical by far. And I don't really understand the scan. Are you trying to optimize the length of the formula, or the depth?

Comment: i want to minimize the numer of terms.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually provably impossible to get a subexponential number of terms for this function: see http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~sk1233/courses/topics-S13/lec4.pdf